# Create custom module in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, module

I am new in CodeIgniter framework. I want to create custom module in Ci. But dont know the workflow to create a new module. I searched google but didnot able to get a proper answer. Please  help me. 
It is helpful to give a sample code/link where I can find how to create new module in CI.

Comment: Do you want module or model ?

Comment: There is HMVC for modules for codeIgniter 3 and above https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For achieve this, you need to create a HMVC structure...

Please find below link for help in this context...

http://developers.ph/codeigniter/hmvc-pattern-codeigniter-php-framework/

Please test well after use any code...
Please also check comments on this article for further help...
Let me know in case of any issue...

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am checking the link now.

Comment: @Asish  is there any need to enable the module or the module will automatically enabled?

Answer (score 0):

**2019 update**

Firstly I'm sure the answer link was good but unfortunately it now redirects to a spam page.

Secondly although there is no full way to do this natively within Codeigniter there is something called "packages" which can be used instead:

https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/loader.html

This works in v3 and allows you to create an `application/modules/your_module` folder and then access libraries and models by calling `$this->load->add_package_path(APPPATH.'modules/resources', FALSE);`. It would require a controller in the generic controllers folder but you could equally put these in a controllers/modules folder to separate them further.

I've seen alternative Github packages etc which are now no longer in date so I would advise this method as its a default option.